# simple url rewriting need

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I need a simple redirect for my pages.

I need the following rewritten:

```
http://abc.de/application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/268/web/Aktivreisen-Wanderreisen.htm    http://abc.de/aktivreisen-schottland.html
http://abc.de/application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/270/web/Busrundreisen.htm http://abc.de/busrundreisen-schottland.html
http://abc.de/application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1223/web/Ferienhotels.htm   http://abc.de/hotels-schottland.html
http://abc.de/application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1217/web/Auto-Rundreisen.htm    http://abc.de/auto-rundreisen-schottland.html
http://abc.de/application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1222/web/Stadthotels.htm    http://abc.de/hotels-schottland.html
http://abc.de/application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1212/web/Unterkunftsschecks.htm http://abc.de/unterkunftsschecks-schottland.html
```

The problem is that `/application/index.cfm` does not exist and the server displays a 404 not found irrespective of how I configure  `http.conf` or the `.htaccess` file.

What should I put in my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example above you'd need to rewrite each one individually. The reason is that there is no repeatable mapping pattern between the `.htm` pages and the ones you're rewriting to:

```
Rewrite Engine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/268/web/Aktivreisen-Wanderreisen.htm    http://abc.de/aktivreisen-schottland.html [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/270/web/Busrundreisen.htm   http://abc.de/busrundreisen-schottland.html [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1223/web/Ferienhotels.htm   http://abc.de/hotels-schottland.html [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1217/web/Auto-Rundreisen.htm    http://abc.de/auto-rundreisen-schottland.html [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1222/web/Stadthotels.htm    http://abc.de/hotels-schottland.html [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule application/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/idLand/44/idReiseart/1212/web/Unterkunftsschecks.htm http://abc.de/unterkunftsschecks-schottland.html [NC,R=301]
```